# Javascript onclick change variable value

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I am new to JavaScript and I need some help. I am making a website and I have several images of team members that if clicked (so I'm guessing the `onclick` event) will change the variable values corresponding to that team member. For instance, if I click on a picture of Bill Gates, in a separate div, I need to have a variable (let's say `Name`) change value to Bill Gates. Then, if I click on an image of Steve Jobs, the variables containing Bill Gates' data will get overwritten with the data of Steve Jobs. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming mark-up like the following:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img class="people" data-subject="Steve Jobs" src="path/to/imageOfSteve.png" />
    <img class="people" data-subject="Bill Gates" src="path/to/imageOfBill.png" />
</div>
<span id="caption"></span>
```

Then a relatively simple, and plain JavaScript, approach:

```
function identifySubject(image, targetEl) {
    if (!image) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var targetNode = document.getElementById(targetEl) || document.getElementById('caption'),
            person = image.getAttribute('data-subject');
            text = document.createTextNode(person);
        if (targetNode.firstChild.nodeType == 3) {
            targetNode.firstChild.nodeValue = person;
        }
        else {
            targetNode.appendChild(text);
        }
    }
}

var images = document.getElementsByClassName('people');
for (var i=0, len=images.length; i<len; i++) {
    images[i].onclick = function(e){
         identifySubject(this, 'caption');
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/k7VUx/).

Answer (score 0):

`Onclick` attribute is right. You need to add the name of a javascript function to the image's onclick attribute (eg `<img src="" onclick="changeVariable()"...`).

If you want text on the page to change depending on who you click on, you'll need to look at selecting divs in Javascript using `getElementById()` or similar and look at the InnerHTML property.

See: http://woork.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/how-to-change-text-using-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
<img src="path/to/image1"  onclick="getValue('bill gates')" />
<img src="path/to/image2"  onclick="getValue('steve jobs')"/>
<div id="show_value"></div>

<script>
function getValue(val){
    document.getElementById('show_value').innerHTML = val
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. It doesn't let me give +1 because I don't have 15 reputation but when it lets me, I'll do that. Everyone else as well, thank you.

Comment: It works, certainly but good luck maintaining that code and updating the function calls when (and *not* 'if') you want to change and update the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <div class="member"><img src="billgates.jpg" /><span>Bill Gates bla bla</span></div>
 <div class="member"><img src="stevejobs.jpg" /><span>Steve Jobs bla bla</span></div>
 <div id="variables"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('.member img').click(function(){
        $('#variables').html($(this).closest('span').html());
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes, it's JavaScript, but it's worth mentioning that it does require the use of the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/). Also, why `html()` and not `text()`?

Comment: sure, true about jQuery. Well use of html is because if user wants to include markup data it should work. Also note that CSS should set the span elements to display="none"